# How to change default name in createTempFile?

Tags: java

This is the code I am using:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class GetTempFilePathExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        try{
            //create a temp file
            File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".tmp"); 
            System.out.println("Temp file : " + temp.getAbsolutePath());
        //Get tempropary file path
            String absolutePath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
            String tempFilePath = absolutePath.
                substring(0,absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
            System.out.println("Temp file path : " + tempFilePath);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

I get this result:
*C:\Users\mkyong\AppData\Local\Temp\temp-file-name**79456440**.tmp*

Is it possible to make so that the result is saved without the additional name? (Example, `C:\Users\mkyong\AppData\Local\Temp\temp-file-name.tmp`) Thanks!

Comment: I believe the idea of `createTempFile` is to create a unique file name. It uses the number to make sure it is unique

Comment: Why do you want a temporary file with a particular name?

Comment: The answer might be _"well then don't use createTempFile, just create a regular file"_ or it might be _"you shouldn't care what the name of the file is"_ — it depends on what you plan to do with the file, but as others said, the whole idea of createTempFile is that it has a name no other file has.

Comment: Because I want to use my template name in the form "yyyy-mm-dd_HH.mm.ss". Or is it a bad idea?

Comment: @Tomas - if you are creating an actual _temporary_ file that is going to go away by itself, you shouldn't care what the file's name is or where it is stored. Once you've got that `temp` File object just pass it around. Temp file names are guaranteed not to collide with an existing file. If you care about the filename, that may be a sign that this is a file you want to keep. The actual answer to your stated question _*"How to change default name in createTempFile?"*_ is: You Can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Q: How to change default name in createTempFile?

The answer:

     *You can't.*

If you could you would invalidate the guarantees of `createTempFile` which, according to [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)), are:

1. The file denoted by the returned abstract pathname did not exist
   before this method was invoked, and
2. Neither this method nor any of
   its variants will return the same abstract pathname again in the
   current invocation of the virtual machine.

If you care about the filename maybe `createTempFile()` is not the appropriate way to create the file.

You ***can*** find out what the system temp file directory is and create your own file there, as @MadcoreTom shows, but you will have to manage the possibility of filename collisions yourself.

An alternative strategy to using `createTempFile` depends on what you are using the file for and why you care what it's named, which you don't state.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understood everything!

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
public class GetTempFilePathExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // create a temp file
        // File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".tmp");
        String folderLocation = System.getenv("temp");
        String fileName = "aa.tmp";
        File temp = new File(folderLocation + File.separator + fileName);
        if (temp.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("Temp file : " + temp.getAbsolutePath());
            // Get tempropary file path
            String absolutePath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
            String tempFilePath = absolutePath.substring(0,
                    absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
            System.out.println("Temp file path : " + tempFilePath);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the idea of `createTempFile` is to create a unique file name. It uses the number to make sure it is unique. Each time you create a temporary file it is *guaranteed* (?) that there is no existing file with the same name.

You could also use `temp.getParentFile()` instead of the `substring` & absolute path that you're using.

If you're only using windows, you could use something like this, which gets the environment variable (the same as `%temp%` in `cmd`)

```
String tempDir = new File(System.getenv("temp")).getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Sorry, but as a path associated with the file name?