# Alternative for File.createTempFile?

Tags: java, file

I don't want the extra number after file name when it is created using createTempFile. But I believe it is not possible to remove them. ([How to change default name in createTempFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334440/how-to-change-default-name-in-createtempfile)).

In my case file name is very important. I cannot use `new File()` as it will create a file in local every-time.

Can someone suggest alternatives?

Comment: Why not just do `File f = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "AnythingYouWant.txt"):`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a temporary directory, which will be created in the directory that according to your operating system is the right place to create temporary directories, using [`Files.createTempDirectory(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.String,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)).

In the directory that you created that way, you can create any file you like, using any filename you like.